# How to get the instagram username from instagram messenger webhook

Tags: instagram-api, messenger

I have successfully configured the instagram webhook but I am receiving instagram User ID from this.

I have already tried various API which are suggested for grabbing username.

I think there is difference bwteeen getting username by Instragram Scoped User ID.

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. in v12 you would make this API call after having received the webhook and use the IGSID for it.

Instagram does not expose the handle, for a matter of privacy I suppose.

Also, no webhook includes contact details in FB or IG, but does for WhatsApp.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/instagram/features/user-profile/